# How to fetch value from within iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, get

```
<iframe src="test.html" id="iframe" ></iframe>
</br>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="get()">
</br>
<input id="xtext" type="text">
```

for example (test.html) contains this text :

```
<td class=\"datatable-cell\">61.00%<\/td>
```

When I press the Start button, I want to fetch the value (61.00%), and place it in the textinput

*Note that the value in the example (61.00%) is variable

Greetings :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get `61.00%` by

```
const iframe = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow;
const value = iframe.document.getElementsByClassName('datatable-cell')[0].innerText;
```

If you want to change it, just change `value`.

Comment: Ninja'd by 20 seconds :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const iframe = document.getElementByID("iframe").contentWindow;

let text = iframe.document.querySelector(".datatable-cell").innerHTML;
```

Though, beware of scripting attacks, if you don't trust the iframe content.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery

```
$('.xtext')[0].click(function() {   
  $('#iframe').contents().$(".datatable-cell").html();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this my code :

```
<iframe src="http://www.golanpal.com/ahmad/test.txt" id="iframe" ></iframe>
</br>
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="get()">
</br>
<input id="xtext" type="text">

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function get() {

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!?????????????

}
</script>
```

in The text.txt file contains a value of (61.00%)

i want When press the Start button, I want to fetch the value (61.00%), and place it in the textinput (xtext)

*Note that the value in the example (61.00%) is variable